# How to add floating textview on one element of a recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, floating

I have a RecyclerView as follows

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/drawerList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/nav_header_container"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
```

I have a string array like this

```
 <string-array name="my_array">
    <item>@string/item_1</item>
    <!--<item>@string/item_2</item>-->
    <item>@string/item_3</item>
    <item>@string/item_4</item>
    <item>@string/item_5</item>
    <item>@string/item_6</item>
```

This string array is used to display data in RecyclerView. I want to display a textview alongside with item_4, **Is it possible?  How to make it?**

Comment: describe your problem properly.

Comment: did it get solved?

Answer (score 1):

From Activity Pass this list to RecyclerView adapter

```
try {
      String[] array = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_array);
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
      list = Arrays.asList(array);

      //pass this list to RecyclerView adapter

    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onBindViewHolder method just put a check for the element you want to display differently and do what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Some solutions:

1.- You can concat a string to the 4th item when you check the position in the onBindViewHolder.

2.- You can create a layout and inflate it on onCreateViewHolder which has two textViews one for the items and one for the text that will go next to it. When you detect that you need to show the second textview change the content and the visibility of the textview.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/items"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewNextToItemOfChoice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then on code you just change the visibility of textview "textViewNextToItemOfChoice" and the content of it.

I think you should make an object (You own model) instead of using just an array of string to populate the list. In that way you can create an object with 2 Strings and in the adapter when you check if it has both string you  show them.